# SPO calendar overlays

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, overlay

A user has a calendar with overlays from other departments.  However, the user only wants to see entries from people he supervises. There are 5 different calendars with several people working in a department.  Is it possible to pull entries from *particular individuals* from those 5 calendars and overlay them into one?  Example: Department boss supervises 5 managers.  Each of those managers maintain a leave calendar for their respective shop.  Dept boss wants leave overlayed from each calendar.  However, Dept boss only wants to overlay the leave from the managers he supervises, not the other employees in those shops.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Calendar Overlays feature on SharePoint Online? If not, please have a try. You can combine multiple calendars and view all events from both calendars (technically up to 10 calendars) in a single view.

There is a blog for your reference:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/01/create-calendar-overlay-in-sharepoint-online.html

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I am checking to see if you have a chance to see the following answer. If you have any doubts about this issue, please feel free to reply.